# Swift 2: why elapsed var is said being left immutable value?

Tags: swift2

In the following code snippet I've got this compiler error which I don't understand: "Left side of mutating operator has immutable type 'CGFloat'"

```
func getElapsed(now now: CGFloat, start: CGFloat) -> String {

    var elapsed = now - start

    let day  = Int(elapsed / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));    elapsed -=  day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    let hour = Int(elapsed / (     60 * 60 * 1000));    elapsed -=      hour * 60 * 60 * 1000
    let min  = Int(elapsed / (          60 * 1000));    elapsed -=            min * 60 * 1000
    let sec  = Int(elapsed /                 1000);     elapsed -=                 sec * 1000

    return "\(day) days, \(hour) hours, \(min) mins, \(sec) secs, \(elapsed) millis"
}
```

Comment: since day is in int and inferred type to elapsed will be on Float...so you are getting the error...try casting the day into CGFloat

Comment: Lol. True! The error message did misled me. Add in the answer so that I can valid it.

Comment: It's more efficient to declare `elapsed` as `Int` with `Int(now - start)` and remove all other `Int` conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't give up on the Ints so fast. Note that this is what gives you the net days in Integer, so then you can deduct them from the overall accumulated elapsed and get a remainder that holds the hours, mins, and so on.
If you let the Int of and everything will be in float you'll miss the point (also in cases of high elapsed value you might get negatives)
You should keep the Ints. On the minus operation - just cast the "day" / "hour"... into CGFloat

see code :

```
func getElapsed(now now: CGFloat, start: CGFloat) -> String
{
    var elapsed = now - start

    let day : Int = Int(elapsed  / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); elapsed -=  CGFloat(day)  * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    let hour: Int = Int(elapsed  / (     60 * 60 * 1000)); elapsed -=  CGFloat(hour) * 60 * 60 * 1000
    let min : Int  = Int(elapsed / (          60 * 1000)); elapsed -=  CGFloat(min)  * 60 * 1000
    let sec : Int  = Int(elapsed /                 1000);  elapsed -=  CGFloat(sec)  * 1000

    return "\(day) days, \(hour) hours, \(min) mins, \(sec) secs, \(elapsed) millis"
}
```

Usage Example:
getElapsed(now: 5000000000, start:100);  // = 57d, 20h, 53min, 19sec, 900ml

Tested successfully on Playground 7.2